# Is the Higgs field really disconnected from gravity?

Tags: gravity, higgs

I would like to understand better the role of Higgs mass in the gravitational interaction. I read here in some posts, that the Higgs mass has nothing to do with gravitation. Is it justified to say that? Gravitation acts on "energy" rather than mass but it is only mass, among the physical observables, which provides an equivalent to energy in contrast to electrical charge for example.

Hadron masses are generated by QCD but doesn`t one need still Higgs-massive quarks for this? If so, planet masses are connected to the Higgs mass.

In the picture of general relativity space-time curvature causes gravitation but remembering Kepler`s laws, why should be "Higgs-based" mass unessential to gravitation, where it is the correct input, describing the orbits of planets etc.?

Sorry, that I mix a few questions and it is a bit unstructured.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54415/

Answer (score 4):

You say:

> but it is only mass, among the physical observables, which provides an equivalent to energy in contrast to electrical charge for example.

But this isn't true. Electric fields are included in the stress-energy tensor, and indeed the charge shows up in the [Reissner-Nordström](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric) metric for a charged black hole.

As you've read in other questions, mass and energy (including electrostatic energy) are interchangable in the stress-energy tensor so in the respect there is no connection between the Higgs mechanism and gravitation. Above the electroweak transition all fundamental particle masses go to zero but their gravitational fields do not disappear.